# Update all link in master word doc at once and also retain master excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word

I have over 50 links from a 'master' excel spreadsheet to a master word document, which is my report. These are 'paste special' objects, so any changes in the spreadsheet will be reflected in the word document when updated. I want to be able to rename my excel spreadsheet and word document that correspond to a clients name, however when I rename them, the links continue to be pulled from the 'master' excel file.

How can I edit or update all the excel links in the new word document all at once, rather than one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Dim f As Field

For Each F in ThisDocument.Fields

    f.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = "C:\users\user1\desktop\NewName.xlsx"

Next f
```